# How to run Pootle via Docker

Tags: docker, configuration, pootle

Due to Windows platfom, I have decided to install Pootle via Docker (first time that i use it) for my projects, following this guide https://hub.docker.com/r/1drop/pootle/

I have created and verified superuser (no problem until this step) but after that .. chaos . I cant configure how to actually access the server at my browser .

I have tried by using pootle shell with the following command `pootle start` getting " Starting CherryPy server, listening on port 8000" but still I cant access the server.

I have also tried to use the `docker-compose up` command as an alternative but still nothing.

Do i have to make some further configurations ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using docker toolbox?

Comment: No , just  windows powershell

Comment: There is are different installations for windows. There is dockertl toolbox and docker for windows.

Comment: I have succesfully installed and run separately another translation tool like Pootle , so i dont think that it has to do with docker installation .

Comment: Could you include your docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile, as well as the commands you're using to run the container?

Comment: I have used the files from https://github.com/1drop/pootle . Starting by the commands from the same link at the instructions section until the command "pootle verify_user --all" . Then I tried "pootle start" and "docker-compose up" as i have mentioned above .